# Kubernates, Ingress controller and certificate

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, self-signed-certificate, ingress-controller

Good morning at all,
my problem is deploy of my application. Before explain my problem i give you a context:

- I have .net rest api application
- Scope of my application is make a middleware for final user versus another app (MotherAPP)
- My application expose REST API to my SPA App (for final user)
- My application expose 2 SOAP Service to allow MotherAPP to send me notify

Now, MotherAPP force me to create self-signed certificate for this SOAP Service. In this way the communication chanel from and to MotherAPP is safe. My certificate has Common name (CN): xxxxxxx (CN name is forced from MotherAPP. I cannot change it)

I want deploy my app on kubernates/docker.

My problem is:

- I build my "Deployment". In this moment only one replica
- I build my clusterIP Service to expose my POD into cluster
- **I want expose two ingress controller. One for my API with certificate of my domain provider and other with self-signed certificate.**

i installed nginx controller but seems impossibile build an ingress controller with host different to Common name of certificate. Ingress Controller not return that certificate. Error return from nginx is:

**"x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match [host]"**

How can i expose my cluster outside with my self-signed certificate?

I hope to find solution or alternative of my idea

**UPDATE:**
I try to install also minikube and i follow google step to create ingress controller and ingress [minikube guide][1]

When i add certificate and annotation to bypass common name check ingress controll return however default kubernates certificate.

Annotations used to bypass check are:

- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify: "off"
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-server-name: "fe.com"
- nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name: "fe.com"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this annotation [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name](http://nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-name) then place the CN of your self-signed certificate. Ensure that you also use annotation [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify](http://nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-verify) then set to “off”.

If ever these annotations did not work, you can also follow this [link](https://snyk.io/blog/setting-up-ssl-tls-for-kubernetes-ingress/) as a guidance on how to configure self-signed certificates to nginx-ingress. The link uses nginx-ingress and self-signed certificate as a sample for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I somewhat understand what you want to achieve. Please read bellow.

> I want expose two ingress controller. One for my API with certificate of my domain provider and other with self-signed certificate.

You rarely need two Ingress Controllers. You need, most likely, one Ingress Controller and two Ingress resources. You can find an explanation about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918876/what-is-a-difference-between-ingress-and-ingress-controller). Additionally, here is [a link](https://I%20think%20I%20somewhat%20understand%20what%20you%20want%20to%20achieve;%20however,%20I%20will%20try%20to%20use%20more%20precise%20terminology.%22) to the official documentation for Ingress Class.

Once you have an Ingress Controller, you need to create a [TLS Kubernetes secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets) and deploy an Ingress resource. You need to specify the secret name as part of the Ingress TLS configuration. An example can be found in [the official Kubernetes documentation for Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls).